# Specify function only for one instance

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in JavaScript and so don't really understand its object model, but as I understood I have to do something like.

```
function set_test(text) { this['test'] = text; };
a = {};
text = 'ok';
a.prototype.ok = set_test(text);
alert(a['test']); #Should be 'ok'
text = 'fail';
a.ok;
alert(a['test']); #Should be 'ok'
```

Can somebody say what's wrong here?

Comment: You should be get some type of error as Object objects don't have prototype property by default

Comment: Also, `a.prototype.ok = set_test(text);` would make `ok` equal to the return value of `set_test` which is `undefined`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LszV8/) is a little different way.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to add a new function to object instance. And I want to be able use this (in context of object instance) from this function.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of JavaScript - http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: @Chad, in fact you give the answer to my question. Thanks. Can you add it like an answer, so I'll accept it.

Comment: @JanKuča, thank you for the link. The problem is javascript object model has received little attention in most of books and this became problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have a prototype by default, and `a.prototype.ok = set_test(text);` would make `ok` equal to the return value of `set_test()` which is `undefined`.

Try doing it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/LszV8/) instead:

```
function set_test(text) { this['test'] = text; };
var a = {
    ok: set_test
},
text = 'ok';

a.ok(text);
alert(a['test']); //Should be 'ok'

text = 'fail';
a.ok(text);
alert(a['test']); //Should be 'fail'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole code is wrong.

You see, in JavaScript, functions are objects and you can pass them around as you wish. The execution context (`this`) depends on the way you invoke a function.

If you store a function in a property of an object and then invoke it by calling `obj.fn()`, the execution context is set to `obj`.

Also notice that you aren't supposed to invoke the function when assigning it as the object's property.

```
function set_test(text) { this['test'] = text; }

var a = {};
a.ok = set_test; // see, no invocation

a.ok('abc');
alert(a['test']); // alerts 'abc'

a.ok('def');
alert(a['test']); // alerts 'def'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in function set_test this['test'] will not work. beacause "this" is not "a". You should define method set_test under object a - then it will work.

I recomend you check Mootools docs - there is much better object model syntax. You can also check Mootools source to get more detail answer to you question and js object model